# Alternative approach to OpenGL View on top of Camera

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera, android-camera

the traditional way of doing a camera preview background with OpenGL on the front is to take two SurfaceViews(one for the camera another for OpenGL) and stack them on top of each other.
The problem is that stacking SurfaceViews is discouraged:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4850fe5c314a3dc6

So what alternatives are there? I was considering the following:

1. Subclass GlSurfaceView, and then call set the Camera preview onto the holder of this subclass: Camera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
2. Don't use GLSurfaceView, instead create your own SurfaceView subclass where you display the Camera preview onto the holder and also draw your openGL. This would require to use OpenGL without GLSurfaceView, has anyone done this before?

I'm not sure if this even is possible or makes sense, since it implies displaying the camera preview onto the holder of the surface and at the same time drawing OpenGL on the same surface.
Is there any other sensible alternative to solving the problem without using two SurfaceViews?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply draw multiple layers in OpenGL? OpenGL is not a scene graph, it just draws triangles on the screen and the projection can be changed anytime in the process arbitrarily.

Comment: @datenwolf, why not post as an answer? :)

Comment: @Kos: Because that may not be, what the OP is actually intending.

Comment: @datenwolf: the problem is that to draw in OpenGL the camera images have to be in RGB format, but they are not, so you would have to convert them on the fly. This is possible, but slow.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw the Camera to a offscreen canvas possibly, and then render it as a texture in opengl. I do this with Google Maps, not sure if the Camera API can also do this.

Might not be as reasonable for Camera as binding the texture is a lot of overhead, and I do it rarely, having a bindtexture call 20-30 times a second to make the camera smooth makes stacking surface views sound like a very good idea.

Edit: You can use GL without GlSurfaceView, but you'll need to use EGL and manage the surfaces manually.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to have the camera display the images onto the SurfaceViews SurfaceHolder and at the same time also draw openGl images on the same SurfaceView?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: Just draw everything into a single OpenGL surface. OpenGL is not a scene graph, so you're not bounded by some kind of topology in the layering. It boils down to

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
draw_bottom_layer();

glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | stencil_used_as_mask ? GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT : 0 );
draw_mid_layer();

glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | stencil_used_as_mask ? GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT : 0 );
draw_top_layer();
```

Forget about "initializing" OpenGL's projection, viewport and that stuff. Just set those whenever you see it fit, like at the beginning of each of those draw_*_layer() functions.

Comment: The problem is that to draw in OpenGL the camera images have to be in RGB format, but they are not, so you would have to convert them on the fly. This is possible, but slow.

Comment: You can use a shader to convert YUV to RGB, see http://www.billmark.com/teach/cs395T-03-spring/presentations/Apr29-proj-smith.ppt, page 17. This example needs adaptation on Androoid, because camera produces semi-planar YUV with V and U pixels in one plane.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it yet, so I don't know much about it, but you might find [SurfaceTexture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) useful.